# PHP json_encode with array only returns first element?

Tags: php, json

I'm attempting to encode some values in JSON, so I can use them within other applications and also create a web API <strike>for them.</strike> to access them.
I have this SQL method to grab data from my database:

```
function getAllMessages() {
    return getConnection()->query("SELECT * FROM allMessages ORDER BY programTimestamp DESC");
}
```

and I have this method to convert the data retrieved in JSON:

```
while( $row = getAllMessages()->fetch_assoc()) {
        $json[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode( $json );
```

I've also tried this:

```
echo json_encode(getAllMessages()->fetch_assoc());
```

and I only get the first element/value returned from the SQL query.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong.Are you sure you have more than 1 value in the db?

Comment: @Mihai yup, there are other values within the database. They appear on the website itself, just not when I use json_encode.

Comment: In your while loop if you do `echo $row[someColumn];` do you get the expected results?

Comment: @Mihai, odd, it displays the same message over and over again.

Comment: @Mihai, seems like I solved the problem. Apparently directly using while ($row = getAllMessages) doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure that your code is exactly as above?. Your `while` loop will result in a infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
while( $row = getAllMessages()->fetch_assoc() ) {
```

produce an infinite loop: at each iteration, you call `getAllMessages()` and fetch first row, so `while` never ends unless that you have no result or boolean (False) result.

Change it in this way:

```
$rows = getAllMessages();
while( $row = $rows->fetch_assoc() )
{
    ...
}
```